# Action Script 3: Addchild within an already added child issue

Tags: actionscript-3, addchild

My issue is that i get an error when my function addSpotlight is called.

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at BubbleBoy_fla::MainTimeline/addSpotlight()
    at BubbleBoy_fla::MainTimeline/policeHeli()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

My code is this:

```
//Adding Helicopter
function addHelicopter(xLocation: int, yLocation: int, passSpeedX, passSpeedY): void {
    var helicopter: Helicopter = new Helicopter(xLocation, yLocation, passSpeedX, passSpeedY);
    back.addChild(helicopter);
    heliList.push(helicopter);
    playFly();
}

//Adding Spotlight
function addSpotlight(xSpotlightLocation: int, ySpotlightLocation: int, spotlightSpeedX): void {
    var spotlight: Spotlight = new Spotlight(xSpotlightLocation, ySpotlightLocation, spotlightSpeedX);
    back.helicopter.addChild(spotlight);
    spotlightList.push(spotlight);
}
```

The reason i am doing this is because the helicopter can be destroyed and the spotlight gets removed at the same time, but if you don't destroy the helicopter and the spotlight hits you then you are caught.

I previously had my code just add the spotlight to the back container then i lined it up with the helicopter, but then this would only remove the first spotlight in the array.

```
if (heliList.length > 0) {
    for (var h: int = 0; h < heliList.length; h++)
        for (var l: int = 0; l < spotlightList.length; l++) {
            if (heliList[h].hitTestPoint(boy.x + upBumpPoint.x, boy.y + upBumpPoint.y, true)) {
                trace("SCORE POINTS")
                score += 100;
                playCrash();
                playFly();
                heliList[h].removeHeli();
                spotlightList[l].removeSpotlight();

                //policeTimer.start();
            }
        }
}
```

Any suggestions on these 2 issues??

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `addSpotlight` use:

```
trace('spotlight: ', spotlight);
trace('back: ', back);
trace('back.helicopter: ', back.helicopter);
trace('spotlightList: ', spotlightList);
```

Whatever is missing - it causes the issue :)

Comment: Ok, so i get: back.helicopter:  undefined. So i assume this is causing the problem? How do i fix it?

Comment: Something like: `back.addChild(helicopter); helicopter.name = 'helicopter';` and later on `back.getChildByName('helicopter').addChild(spotlight);`

Comment: The first is always good to have. The second can be skipped with `public dynamic class` (dynamic is the important here, so you can use `back.helicopter` without `getChildByName`)